# Can I compile in less files from a different source?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, compilation, client, less

Ok so I work for a company that uses Bootstrap and less css. Right now for each client they include all our "core" less files that dont change along with the less files that are only for that customer. We want to clean this up and have a central location for the "core" files and then in each client folder all we have are the 2-3 less files that are only for the client.

Can bootstrap compile less from multiple locations?

This is structure as to what we have now and what we want.

**What we have now:**

Client 1:

- Customer Less files
- "Core" less files

Client 2:

- Customer Less files
- "Core" less files

Client 3:

- Customer Less files
- "Core" less files

**What we want:**

"Core" less files

Client 1:

- Customer Less files

Client 2:

- Customer Less files

Client 3:

- Customer Less files

Hope this makes sense. Thanks

Comment: My experience is that stability is generally better, as minor changes to the core files could have unexpected consequences for the other sites using the same base. Unless you set up a CDN with explicit versioning, you're probably better off managing separate core files.

Comment: You could create your own [nuget package](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package) to distribute your core files.  That way individual projects can opt to upgrade versions at a time that is convenient, but you can still have a versioned, centralized repository.

Answer (score 0):

I expect your question is about client side compiling of your less code (see: http://lesscss.org/#client-side-usage).

When using the less.js client side compiler you can include more than one file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="core.less">
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="client.less">
<script src="js/less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

When you move core.less in the above situation to an other domain:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="http://yourdomain.com/core.less">
```

You will end up in a cross domain issue in the first. This can be fixed by enabeling CORS, see: http://enable-cors.org/. On the domain where core.less has been installed, the server should send an  `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header.

less.js loads the less files with a `XMLHttpRequests` which supports CORS for most modern browsers see http://caniuse.com/#search=cors. More details can be found at http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Notice that the less.js compiler compiles each file independent from each other in a different scope. So the client.less file in this example can not use mixins and variable defined in core.less.

Please also notice that you should not use client side compiling for production in most cases because of performance issues.